# Single sends must include a subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I am trying to send SMS from php, for some strange reason I have started getting this error.

> Single sends must include a subscriber

Whereas I am providing the subscriber with the send definition.

```
try {
        /* Create the Soap Client */
        $client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));

        /* Set username and password here */
        $client->username = 'userName';
        $client->password = 'Password';

        $tsd = new ExactTarget_SMSTriggeredSendDefinition();

        $tsd->Name = "ABCDE";
        $tsd->CustomerKey = "xxxxx"; // set external key/unique identifier for the triggered send definition
        $tsd->SendToList = false;
        $tsd->SendToListSpecified = false;
$ts = new ExactTarget_SMSTriggeredSend();

        $ts->SMSTriggeredSendDefinition = new SoapVar($tsd, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'SMSTriggeredSendDefinition', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");
        $subscriber = new ExactTarget_Subscriber();
        $subscriber->SubscriberKey = "validEmail";


        $ts->Subscriber = $subscriber;

        $ts->Number="90909090909";
        $ts->Message="Hello from me";   

// create SoapVar object
        $object = new SoapVar($ts, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'SMSTriggeredSend', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");

        // create request object
        $request = new ExactTarget_CreateRequest();
        $request->Options = NULL;
        $request->Objects = array($object);

        // Create the triggered send definition
        $results = $client->Create($request);
```

Result

```
["StatusCode"]=>
    string(5) "Error"
    ["StatusMessage"]=>
    string(39) "Single sends must include a subscriber."
    ["OrdinalID"]=>
    int(0)
    ["ErrorCode"]=>
    int(33100)
    ["NewID"]=>
    int(0)
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a PHP example handy, but I don't see where $subscriber is associated with the request object.  That would likely be the root cause of the error.

With other SDK languages, you generally create a subscriber object, assign its attributes (sub key, mobile number), then assign that subscriber object to the triggered send object prior to performing the InvokeCreate.

An example from .NET:

```
SMSTriggeredSend ts = new SMSTriggeredSend();
... 
SMSTriggeredSend ts = new SMSTriggeredSend();
ts.Number = "1-123-456-7890";
ts.Message = "TEST SMS";

SMSTriggeredSendDefinition tssd= new SMSTriggeredSendDefinition();
tssd.CustomerKey = "12345";

ts.SMSTriggeredSendDefinition = tssd;

Subscriber sub = new Subscriber();
sub.SubscriberKey = "1-123-456-7890";//The Subscriber Key of a record on the All     SMS Subscribers List

ts.Subscriber = sub;
```

Specifically referring to the very last line here, where the subscriber object called 'sub' is set to the subscriber property of ts.

Comment: Thanks David for looking and replying, Yes you are right, Sorry I missed to paste $ts->Subscriber = $subscriber; line here  but in my original code it is present.

Comment: Even I am getting subscriber details from ET with in response message

["Subscriber"]=>
      object(stdClass)#8 (4) {
        ["PartnerKey"]=>
        NULL
        ["ObjectID"]=>
        NULL
        ["EmailAddress"]=>
        string(26) "xxxxxxxxx"
        ["SubscriberKey"]=>
        string(18) "xxxxxxxxx"
      }